# jQuery or Javascript solution to make a vertical navigation sidebar like blogger dynamic view

Tags: jquery, css, navigation, sidebar

I am looking for a simple jQuery or Javascript solution to make a vertical navigation sidebar.
Something like blogger dynamic view gadget bar: http://nildarar.blogspot.com/

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this script, works for me !

http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-mega-menu-plugin/examples/

> This plugin creates vertical mega menus from standard HTML nested
>   lists, allowing users to view all available menu options for each
>   top-level menu item.

Answer (score 0):

you can use both but in jQuery you can put your condition if this condition is done you can add style to the `div/span` you want to scroll
if you have this `div`

```
<div id="tableTag" style="height:120px;">
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>caption1</th>
         <th>caption2</th>
         .
         .
         etc
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

i prefer using JQuery in this case because it is easy to control and easy to add styles and attributes :

```
// get Data
// make your condition :
if(rowCount >= 10)
{
   $("#tableTag").css('overflow', 'auto');
}
```